# Is it a good practice to modify a spring data result query like this?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'd like your opinion on a practice I use, I'm not on that it's very clean.

The idea is to add a field based on demand, so non-persistent.
I leave on the example of a garage that has several cars of different brands and colours. The request must display all the cars in the garage and if the colour corresponds to that requested, the calculated field "**as selected color**" must display **true or false** like in this exemple:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "color": "red",
            "brand": "opel",
            "garage": {
                "name": "Garage1"
            },
            HERE => "as selected color": true
        },
        {
            "color": "black",
            "brand": "bmw",
            "garage": {
                "name": "Garage1"
            },
            HERE => "as selected color": false
        },
        {
            "color": "red",
            "brand": "fiat",
            "garage": {
                "name": "Garage1"
            },
            HERE => "as selected color": true
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

To get this result that is composed of information from two entities linked by a OneToMany relationship, I use a list of Objects like this :

```
@PostMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<HashMap> process(@RequestBody Map<String, String> request) throws Exception {
...    
    List<Object> garageWithCars = new ArrayList<Object>();
    garageWithCars = garageRepository.findCars();

    // Set if color is same as asked
    // Is it a good practice ?
    for (Object tempObject : garageWithCars) {
        if (tempObject.getClass() == Car.class) {
            ((Car)tempObject).setIsSelectedColor(color);
        }
    }

    map.put("List", garageWithCars);
    return new ResponseEntity<HashMap>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This does not seem to me to be very pro, so I would like your opinion on this way of doing, thank you.

Here is **GarageRepository** :

```
@Repository
public interface GarageRepository  extends JpaRepository<Garage,Long> {
    @Query("select c from Car as c")
    List<Object> findCars();
}
```

The **Car** Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "color")
    String color;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    String brand;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("as selected color")
    Boolean isSelectedColor = false;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="garage_id", nullable = false)
    private Garage garage;

    Car() {}

    public Boolean getIsSelectedColor() {
        return isSelectedColor;
    }

    public void setIsSelectedColor(String selectedColor) {
        if(color.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedColor)) {
            this.isSelectedColor = true;
        }
    }
    ... getters and setters
}
```

And **Garage** Class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="garage")
public class Garage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "garage_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "garage")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Car> cars = new HashSet<>();

    public Garage() {}

    ... getters and setters
}
```